# Can't turn off fontified subscripts in Emacs 24

Tags: auctex, subscripts, superscripts

Under Emacs 24.3 and Auctex, the sub/superscript fontification is occurring outside math modes. This appears in either Beamer or normal LaTeX docs.

Per [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74355/annoying-emacs-autoformatting-in-latex-mode), I've included the following lines in my `.emacs.d`:

```
    ;; disable annoying fontification in latex
    (setq font-latex-fontify-script nil)
```

However, this only appears to fix the behavior for a subset of letters for the subscript, and not at all for the superscript. Something like `_p` is fine. But `_v` gets set as the subscript. Both `^v` and `^p` get set as superscripts.

Has anyone else run into this problem? This is AucTeX 11.86 and Emacs 24.3, running on ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Math-mode fontification appearing in normal text isn't normal, as far as I can remember (I don't have emacs 24 or auctex 11.86 here to test, unfortunately). I would search for "hidden" things tricking auctex into thinking it's in math mode. The best candidate is a `$` in a comment. If it happens even at the very beginning of the document, this comment won't help you though.

Comment: Update: it appears this is caused by bad behavior in `latex-pretty-symbols.el`, which was loaded as part of the Emacs starter kit.

Comment: So what was the resolution for this? What can I do to disable annoying formatting - driving me insane right now

Comment: @ilya are you sure `(setq font-latex-fontify-script nil)` does not work you? I tried it on Emacs 24.4 with the latest AucTeX, which works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following:

```
(fset 'tex-font-lock-suscript 'ignore)
```

Answer (score 1):

See some of the answers [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35782/deactivate-subscripts-and-superscripts-raising-lowering-in-latex-mode). In your .emacs.d, place the line

`(setq tex-fontify-script nil)`

The font-latex-fontify-script property that you reference applies only if you are using the font-latex scheme (which comes packaged with things like AUCTeX). For a generic setup, use tex-fontify-script.